# Bash arrays and case statements - review my script

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
# Change the environment in which you are currently working.
# Actually, it calls the relevant 'lettus.sh' script

if [ "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" == "$0" ]; then
    echo "Try running this as \". chenv $1\""
    exit 0
fi

usage(){
    echo "Usage: . ${PROG}        -- Shows a list of user-selectable environments."
    echo "       . ${PROG} [env]  -- Select environment."
    echo "       . ${PROG} -h     -- Shows this usage screen."
    return
}

showEnv(){
    # check if index0 exists, assume we have at least the first (zeroth) element
    #if [ -z "${envList}" ]; then
    if [ -z "${envList[0]}" ]; then
        echo "array \$envList is empty! " >&2
        return 1
    fi

    # Show all elements in array (0 -> n-1)
    for i in $(seq 0 $((${#envList[@]} - 1))); do
        echo ${envList[$i]}
    done
    return
}
setEnv(){
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        usage; return
    fi

    case $1 in
        cold)       FILE_TO_SOURCE=/u2/tip/conf/ctrl/lettus_cold.sh;;
        coles)      FILE_TO_SOURCE=/u2/tip/conf/ctrl/lettus_coles.sh;;
        fc)         FILE_TO_SOURCE=/u2/tip/conf/ctrl/lettus_fc.sh;;
        fcrm)       FILE_TO_SOURCE=/u2/tip/conf/ctrl/lettus_fcrm.sh;;
        stable)     FILE_TO_SOURCE=/u2/tip/conf/ctrl/lettus_stable.sh;;
        tip)        FILE_TO_SOURCE=/u2/tip/conf/ctrl/lettus_tip.sh;;
        uat)        FILE_TO_SOURCE=/u2/tip/conf/ctrl/lettus_uat.sh;;
        wellmdc)    FILE_TO_SOURCE=/u2/tip/conf/ctrl/lettus_wellmdc.sh;;
        *)          usage; return;;
    esac

    if $IS_SOURCED; then
        echo "Environment \"$1\" selected."
        echo "Now sourcing file \"$FILE_TO_SOURCE\"..."
        . ${FILE_TO_SOURCE}
        return
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

main(){
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        showEnv; return
    fi

    case $1 in
        -h) usage;;
         *) setEnv $1;;
    esac
    return
}

PROG="chenv"

# create array of user-selectable environments
envList=( cold coles fc fcrm stable tip uat wellmdc )

main "$@"
return
```

If I could, I'd like to get some feedback on a better way to accomplish any of the following:

1. run through the case statement
2. make script trivally simple to maintain/upgrade/update

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `showEnv`, why do you need to check that `envList` is empty when you define it right in the program?

I'd write the array elements one-per-line with:

```
# Show all elements in array
for elem in "${envList[@]}"; do 
    echo "$elem"
done
```

or, more succinctly

```
printf "%s\n" "${envList[@]}"
```

In `setEnv`:

```
case $1 in
    cold|coles|fc|fcrm|stable|tip|uat|wellmdc)
        FILE_TO_SOURCE="/u2/tip/conf/ctrl/lettus_$1.sh" ;;
    *)  usage; return;;
esac
```

or, without duplicating the contents of `envList`:

```
FILE_TO_SOURCE=""
for elem in "${envList[@]}"; do
    if [ "$elem" = "$1" ]; then
        FILE_TO_SOURCE="/u2/tip/conf/ctrl/lettus_$1.sh"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -z "$FILE_TO_SOURCE" ];then 
    usage
    return
fi
```

You might want to check that the relevant file exists

```
if [ ! -f "$FILE_TO_SOURCE" ]; then
    echo "missing config file '$FILE_TO_SOURCE'!"
    echo "contact $maintainer for assistance"
    return 1
fi
```

What is `$IS_SOURCED`? You might want to document how that environment variable is defined.

You don't need the `return` at the end of `main` or at the end of the program.